# Calculating uncertainty from Naive Bayes Classification predictions

Tags: machine-learning, analytics, bayesian, naivebayes

I've implemented a Naive Bayes Classification on a data set that has 3 classifications (Yes, No, and Maybe). Currently I have an array with the probabilities that an input belongs to each one of the 3 classes. I chose the class with the highest probability as my prediction.

I would like to calculate the certainty of my prediction. I'm new to data analytics so I'm not sure if their is a standard way to calculate this, so any resources or advice would help.

Originally I was thinking of doing: (Pm = Prediction Probability , Pb = Probability of other class, Pc = Probability of remaining third class)

`Certainty = Pm/(Pm + Pb + Pc)` or  `Certainty = Pm^2/(Pm^2 + Pb^2 + Pc^2)` but really this is just an arbitrary equation I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're over-thinking this.  If you're using the standard metrics, then

```
Pm + Pb + Pc = 1.0
```

by definition.

Pm *is* the certainty, as computed by the modelling process.